# How to parse JPEG from an API response and send to frontend in Node.js/Express

Tags: node.js, express, server, jpeg, openstreetmap

I'm using Google's Street View Image API to get a jpeg which I then want to pass in a response body from my Node.js/Express backend to my frontend.

Currently, my `getStreetView` function gets a correct response from the Google API. I then pass that `response.body` (the jpeg) in a callback to my own request handler. However, when I make a request to that handler, though the request is successful and contains those headers I've assigned including `'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'`, the image doesn't display. The image data is present, it just isn't being displayed:

[image: Screenshot of Display Failure]

So to reiterate - Postman requests to the API display the image. When my handler calls `getStreetView`, that request is also working. But the image it receives is somehow being lost in translation when passed to GET `/city`.

Is this an encoding issue? I would just send the image URL instead of the image itself, but the url contains my API key - which I thought might make me vulnerable on the client-side. Any help much appreciated!

```
var getStreetView = function(newLat, newLong, callback) {
  var api_key = process.env.API_KEY;
  var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?' +
    'size=' + 400 + 'x' + 400 +
    '&location=' + newLat + ',' + newLong +
    '&fov=' + 120 +
    '&pitch=' + 10 +
    '&key=' + api_key;

  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('getStreetView Error: ', error);
    } else {
      callback(body); //same error when using response.body
    }
  });
};

// REQUEST HANDLING
app.get('/city', function(req, res) {
  City.findOneRandom(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Cities.findOneRandom Error: ', err);
    } else {
      var name = result.name;
      var country = result.country;
      var lat = result.latitude;
      var long = result.longitude;

      randomizeLocation(lat, long, function(newLat, newLong) {
        getStreetView(newLat, newLong, function(image) {
          res.writeHead(200, {
            'City': name,
            'Country': country,
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
          });

          res.end(image);
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: By "the image doesn't display" you mean a blank page?

Comment: Right now I'm making the request in Postman. By 'doesn't display' I mean - instead of showing the image when viewing my response body, a small empty white frame is shown. Will add screenshot. When I make a request directly to the API from Postman, the image itself is shown when viewing the response body.

Comment: **And when the 'Content-Type: image-jpeg' header is not added, the body shows up as long string of characters I don't recognize